# Show that a set is homotopy equivalent with itself

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be some space. Show that $X \cong X$.

I’m reading about homotopy and found this question. It didn’t have any other information about $X$ so I’m not sure if this is enough? The definition is that a set is homotopy equivalent with another set if there is a continuous map $f: X \to X$ for which there is another continuous map $g : X \to X$ such that $g \circ f \cong id_X$ and $f \circ g \cong id_X$. So I would need that $X \ne \emptyset$ and that $X$ has continuous maps?

Comment: The identity map on a topological space $X$ is always continuous. Why must $X$ be non-empty?

Comment: You don't need that $X\neq \emptyset$. Just set $f=g= id_{X}$. The projection $X\times[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is a homotopy from the identity on $X$ into itself, so $gf=fg\cong id_{X}$.

Comment: I think $X\neq \emptyset$ makes $h:X\times [0,1]\to X$ feel like an actual homotopy. Having the empty function be a homotopy from the empty function to the empty function feels a bit weird. I'm sure it's entirely fine if you dive into the specifics, but I completely understand the desire to want to exclude that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given a **nonempty** space $X$ consider the identity map

$$id:X\to X$$
$$id(x)=x$$

and now just put $f=g=id$. Note that the homotopy $f\circ g\cong id$ is simply given by: $H(t,x)=x$ (which is continuous since it is the projection onto second argument, and projections are always continuous). The same homotopy works for $g\circ f\cong id$.

Now you asked whether you need that $X\neq\emptyset$. The empty set is a special case. Technically speaking there is unique function $u:\emptyset\to\emptyset$. This function satisfies $u\circ u =u$. Furthermore the identity $id_\emptyset$ is equal to our $u$ as well, because $id_\emptyset(x)=x$ definition (which can be rewritten as "$\forall x\in \emptyset\ \ (x,x)\in id_\emptyset$") is vacously true. Furthermore given any set $Y$ we have $Y\times\emptyset=\emptyset$. Gathering all that data together we get that $u\circ u\cong id_{\emptyset}$ via empty $H:I\times\emptyset\to\emptyset$ homotopy (which is equal to $u$ as well). Note that the homotopy condition is vacously true as well.

All in all: the statement is also true for $X=\emptyset$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the homotopy $f\circ g\cong id$ is the only one possible"? Of course $H(x,t) =x$ does the job, but there may be many more homotopies from $id$ to $id$.

Comment: @KritikerderElche what I've meant is that in general $H(x,t)=x$ is the only possible definition. With this amount of information. I've rephrased the sentence.